# Vagrant up --no-parallel flag meaning

Tags: docker, vagrant, boot2docker, vagrantfile, dockerfile

Do anyone know what exactly `vagrant up --no-parallel` flag does? I found in the docs that I should use it whenever I am linkink two different containers within same Vagrantfile.

```
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
    config.vm.define "a" do |app|
        app.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
            d.name = "a"
            d.image = "a"
        end
    end
    config.vm.define "b" do |app|
        app.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
            d.name = "b"
            d.image = "b"
            d.link("a:a")
        end
    end
end
```

What should I run if I have Vagrantfile looking like this?

```
vagrant up a --no-parallel && vagrant up b
```

or

```
vagrant up a && vagrant up b --no-parallel
```

or

```
vagrant up --no-parallel
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`--no-parallel` option makes sense when `vagrant up` is used to bring multiple machines up altogether: that is when Vagrantfile declares multiple machines and `vagrant up` is either given no machine names or multiple machine names. In this case, if the provider supports this (and yes, Docker provider does indeed), Vagrant will attempt to bring all requested machines up in parallel, unless `--no-parallel` is given.

So with Docker provider, when linking containers, one may use `--no-paralel` when bringing multiple machines up altogether:

```
$ vagrant up --no-parallel
```

or

```
$ vagrant up /regex to match machine names/ --no-parallel
```

However, if you bring machines up one-by-one with separate commands, it will have no effect (no harm either) if `--no-parallel` is specified or not. So one may simply do:

```
$ vagrant up a && vagrant up b
```